# Optimizing simple for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, optimization, vector

I have some lines of code with a for loop that look like this:

```
somevector2 <- c(length = somevector2_length)

for(string in somevector1){

  df2 <- df1[df1$col1 == string, ]
  ff <- somefunction(df2$col2)
  somevector2 <- c(somevector2, ff)

}
```

From what i understood initializing the vector with the correct length should make the loop faster, but it still takes quite sometimes although the `somefunction(df2$col2)` does some simple operations.`somevector1` it's just a vector of strings

Is there a way to make this loop faster in R? thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but that's not how you are supposed to post a question on SO. :( You should provide a working example. Also, that's not the way to create a vector of a fixed length.

---

Let's see a reproducible example of what you posted:

```
##### this makes your example reproducible

somevector1 <- unique(iris$Species)
df1 <- iris
names(df1) <- paste0("col", 5:1)
somefunction <- sum
somevector2_length <- 3



##### this is your code

# somevector2 <- c(length = somevector2_length) # <- this was wrong
somevector2 <- c()


for(string in somevector1){
 
 df2 <- df1[df1$col1 == string, ]
 ff <- somefunction(df2$col2)
 somevector2 <- c(somevector2, ff)
 
}
```

So this is the final result:

```
somevector2
#>  12.3  66.3 101.3
```

---

What I suggest you is to use this line of code down here, instead of your code.
You will get a similar result (it's a NAMED numeric vector).

```
tapply(df1$col2, df1$col1, somefunction)
#>    setosa versicolor  virginica 
#>      12.3       66.3      101.3
```

You can get rid of the names with `unname()`

Comment: thanks, i didn't know i had to provide always a reproducible example, i'll make sure to do so in future questions

Comment: not always.. there are some situations were you can't... but generally yes... Also, if this is what you were looking for, I would invite you to accept the answer.

Comment: I'm trying to understand this solution you provided, but i don't quite understand the point where this line you provided `tapply(df1$col2, df1$col1, somefunction)` takes into account the filtering of the df based on the string value provided in the for loop as seen in `for(string in somevector1){ df2 <- df1[df1$col1 == string, ]`.

Comment: that line of code replaces your entire code. If you want just some spefic strings, instead of all of them, just filter your dataframe before that line like this: `df1 <- df1[df1$col1 %in% somevector1, ]`